# price is not change based on product attribute prestashop 1.6.0.9

Tags: prestashop-1.6

I am facing issue on my store.

I have Prestashop 1.6.0.9 Version on my product detail page.I have different attribute like color,size etc.Product price is not change based on attribute.

Can anyone have solution?

Answer (score 0):

If u change combination and price still the same you should check your_theme/js/product.js and also check id="our_price_display". Maybe u have changed your code in tpl file and now Jquery cant find our_price_display?